# How can we check the health status of our Stack Exchange community?

Tags: support, statistics

It's in the interest for our community to ensure that our Stack Exchange stays healthy. I'm wondering if there's a way for members to check its health status, by looking at things like number of questions asked and answered per day; number of new contributors; number of active contributors. Is this information available anywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of stats you're asking for can be found in [the site's Area 51 page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136/substrate).

It is worth noting, though, that the queries pulling these stats were defined years ago and haven't been revised recently, so these stats aren't exact indicators of community health, and should instead be used as general reference points.